# Create lists by applying conditions on list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to create 2 lists (list1 with values equal to zero and list 2 with values greater than zero) using a list of tuples (based on its first element). Following is what I am using:

```
a=[(1.2,'197301'),(0,'19980101'),(10,'19010101'),(0,'19830101')]
list1 = [a for a in a if a == 0]
list2 = [a for a in a if a != 0]
```

`list1` gives `[(0, '19980101'), (0, '19830101')]` but `list2` returns: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use the same variable name for the list as inside the list comprehension!! Also, a is not a list of tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redefining `a` during your list comprehension:

```
>>> a=[1.2,'19730101',0,'19980101',10,'19910101',0,'19830101']
>>> list1 = [a for a in a if a == 0]
>>> a
'19830101'
```

Works great if you change the variable:

```
>>> list1 = [i for i in a if i == 0]
>>> list2 = [i for i in a if i != 0]
>>> list1
[0, 0]
>>> list2
[1.2, '19730101', '19980101', 10, '19910101', '19830101']
```